# SpringBoot reading from a table without an entity, edit and save in another table

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

in my system i need to read from table userinout(only have the table no entity,DAO etc..). Then send those data to DateToDayConvert class and save the changed data in the records table(Have a records model,DAo & a controller). I'm not much familiar with spring boot so i don't know how to read data from the database without having an Entity.Thx

DateToDayConvert

```
public class DateToDayConvert {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        //1. Create a Date from String
        for (int i=0;i<args.length;i++) {
            System.out.println("i"+args[i]);

        }
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        String dateInString = "22-01-2015 10:20:56";
        Date date = sdf.parse(dateInString);
        DateToDayConvert obj = new DateToDayConvert();

        //2. Test - Convert Date to Calendar
        Calendar calendar = obj.dateToCalendar(date);
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime());

        //3. Test - Convert Calendar to Date
        String newDate = obj.calendarToDate(calendar);
        System.out.println(newDate);


    }


    //Convert Date to Calendar
    private Calendar dateToCalendar(Date date) {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        return calendar;

    }

    //Convert Calendar to Day
    private String calendarToDate(Calendar calendar) {
        int day= calendar.getTime().getDay();
        int time=calendar.getTime().getHours();
        System.out.println(time);
        switch(day) {
            case 1:
                return "Monday";
            case 2:
                return "Tuesday";
            case 3:
                return "Wednesday";
            case 4:
                return "Thursday";
            case 5:
                return "Friday";
            case 6:
                return "Satarday";
            default:
                return "Sunday";
        }
    }

}
```

Records Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name="records")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)

public class Records {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private int userId;
    private String day;
    private int time;


    public Records() {
    }

    public Records(int userId, String day, int time) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.day = day;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public int getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

[image: Checkinout]

[image: records]

Comment: why do you want to read without Entity?

Comment: because userinout table is generated from a differenet system and i only want to read some of its data

Comment: So use SQL and Spring Data JDBC https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference

Comment: hey thx, but i want to  read from database without creating a model. is there any way to do it?

Comment: If you want to read only some of its data (you are aware of which data), it can still be done with @Entity. In case you still do not want to, use JdbcTemplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    private final String URL = "url";
    private final String USER = "dbuser";
    private final String DRIVER = "driver";
    private final String PASSWORD = "dbpassword";

    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty(URL));
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty(USER));
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty(PASSWORD));
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty(DRIVER));
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

You can now use the JdbcTemplate to fire queries and get desired columns.

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```